# Can I put two seperate Jframe file into one Jframe file in java?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am developing library management system for my project. I have created different `JFrame` form files for adding members, adding books, issuing books. I also created menu.java and header.java. Is it possible for me to put all these file in one `JFrame` form file or a single file. Normally in HTML, we can put 2 or more different page in one page by using FRAMESET tag. Is there any kind thing i can use in java so that i can insert menu.java, header.java. And when i click on button on menu the file opens in main panel? As i am new i am not so much familiar with java so I would like to apologize if i make a silly question.

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you're asking, but it sounds like you need to read up on Swing layout managers - [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html). And from what little I understood, it sounds like `CardLayout` may be a good candidate...

Comment: The concept is just same like in the java api documentation page: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api. You click the link in the left frame, you'll get the content displayed at the right frame.

Comment: +1 for the clarity. And I stand by the points I made above..research different layout managers.

Comment: I have used the different jpanel on top of each other and set the visibility to false. when button is click the visibility is change to true and require jpanel is show. But when i do like this all the codes are in same file and look messy. Using cardlayout is also the same things. i have to do everything in same file. Am i correct? Using FRAMESET in HTML, we can keep the content of different pages in same page. Is there anything in java like that?

Comment: "*we can keep the content of different pages in same page. Is there anything in java like that?*". Yes, `CardLayout` effectively does that.

Comment: @mre: I think your comment above answers the question. Perhaps you should make it an official answer.

Comment: i try to create the different file for classes. But when i put the event in button, than netbeans automatically create private file and i cant edit it. So i can send the variable to other files. is there anyway in which i can access the variable which is declared inside the private class?

Comment: You may need to create public getter and setter (also known as accessor and mutator) methods. Although there are also other ways of getting around this if your code is factored well.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: I need to get the value of variable which is declared inside the private class. So where shall this getter and setter go and how it goes. Can you explain with code please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a basic concept of references.  Basically, you need to supply the various parts of your application with one or references to the view/model of your application.

That would be, for your menu, you would need to pass a reference to the primary view, so when a menu item is clicked, it knows where it can display its results.

For me, I would be hesitant to expose parts of my application unnecessarily, instead, I would pass it some kind of model/manager, that was capable of acting as a go between the view and the actions.  This will of course depend on your underlying requirements.

**A Very Basic Example**

```
public class Parent {
    protected static final double BRIBE = 20.00;
    public Parent() {
        Child child = new Parent(child);
    }

    public double getMoney() {
        return wealth - BRIBE;
    }
}

public class Child {
    private Parent parent;
    public Child(Parent parent) {
        double allowance = parent.getMoney();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But can you explain it in a bit simpler terms please. I am beginner.

Comment: If you're just starting out, I strongly recommend you don't start with Swing.  Swing itself is a complex API that requires you to have a basic understand of OO and programming concepts.  I'd recommend that you take a look [The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) and start with *Trails Covering the Basics*